# add a column to a dataset from the split of two other columns

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have the following dataset in ubuntu and I would like to make an iteration (while or for) in bash in order to generate a new column with the quotient between failed and passed subjects.

```
id, name, country, Continent, grade, passed, failed
1, Louise Smith, UK, Europe, 7, 5, 1
2, Okio Kiomoto, Japan, Asia, 9, 5, 0
3, Ralph Watson, USA, Northern America, 5.6, 5, 2
4, Mary Mcaann, South Africa, Africa, 4.7, 5, 3
5, Jack Thomson, Australia, Oceania, 10, 5, 0
6, N'dongo Mbaye, Senegal, Africa, 7.9, 5, 1
```

To do this I have tried to use the following code in a script. But I can't get any result as I can't find any way to add this new generated column to the current dataset.. Any ideas?

```
while IFS=, read _ _ _ _ _ passed failed; do
newcolumn=$($passed/$failed |bc)

done
```

As a guideline, the desired output would be as follows.

```
id, name, country, Continent, grade, passed, failed, new
1, Louise Smith, UK, Europe, 7, 5, 1, 0.2
2, Okio Kiomoto, Japan, Asia, 9, 5, 0, 0
3, Ralph Watson, USA, Northern America, 5.6, 5, 2, 0.4
4, Mary Mcaann, South Africa, Africa, 4.7, 5, 3, 0.6
5, Jack Thomson, Australia, Oceania, 10, 5, 0, 0
6, N'dongo Mbaye, Senegal, Africa, 7.9, 5, 1, 0.2
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored your code a bit and came up with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

# create new header 
header=$(awk 'NR==1 {print}' s.dat)
printf "%s, new\n" "${header}"

# read data file data rows
while IFS=, read a b c d e passed failed; do
    newcolumn=0

    # avoid divide-by-zero
    if [[ "${passed}" -ne "0" ]] ; then
        newcolumn=$(bc <<<"scale=2; ${failed} / ${passed}")
    fi

    # output data with new generated column
    printf "%s %3.2f\n" "${a}, ${b}, ${c}, ${d}, ${e}, ${passed}, ${failed}, " "${newcolumn}"
done < <(awk 'NR!=1 {print}' s.dat)
```

Contents of s.dat:

```
id, name, country, Continent, grade, passed, failed
1, Louise Smith, UK, Europe, 7, 5, 1
2, Okio Kiomoto, Japan, Asia, 9, 5, 0
3, Ralph Watson, USA, Northern America, 5.6, 5, 2
4, Mary Mcaann, South Africa, Africa, 4.7, 5, 3
5, Jack Thomson, Australia, Oceania, 10, 5, 0
6, N'dongo Mbaye, Senegal, Africa, 7.9, 5, 1
```

Output when executing script:

```
id, name, country, Continent, grade, passed, failed, new
1,  Louise Smith,  UK,  Europe,  7,  5,  1,  0.20
2,  Okio Kiomoto,  Japan,  Asia,  9,  5,  0,  0.00
3,  Ralph Watson,  USA,  Northern America,  5.6,  5,  2,  0.40
4,  Mary Mcaann,  South Africa,  Africa,  4.7,  5,  3,  0.60
5,  Jack Thomson,  Australia,  Oceania,  10,  5,  0,  0.00
6,  N'dongo Mbaye,  Senegal,  Africa,  7.9,  5,  1,  0.20
```

UPDATE - Per OP's question in comments:

Get header row without using awk:

```
header=$(head -n 1 s.dat)
```

Process data rows without using awk:

```
{
     # extra read to skip first row
     read 

     # read data file data rows
     while IFS=, read a b c d e passed failed; do
        newcolumn=0

        # avoid divide-by-zero
        if [[ "${passed}" -ne "0" ]] ; then
            newcolumn=$(bc <<<"scale=2; ${failed} / ${passed}")
        fi

        # output data with new generated column
        printf "%s %3.2f\n" "${a}, ${b}, ${c}, ${d}, ${e}, ${passed}, ${failed}, " "${newcolumn}"
    done

} < s.dat
```

Comment: Your code works but is there any way to avoid using the awk commands?

Comment: @ j_b I've tested your code and it seems to be working but it shows me the following I don't know if it can be avoided somehow "Runtime error (func=(main), adr=14): Divide by zero"

Comment: @oshiono, i cannot reproduce the error you indicate using the sample data you provided.   are you testing using that same data or different data?

Comment: The data I posted is just a sample of the original. After noticing that there are certain registers where "passed" is equal to 0, I think it is normal for it to complain. However, I don't know how I can avoid it

Comment: I added a row to the sample data that includes a "passed" value of 0,  and the code still runs fine without error.   the `if [[ "${passed}" -ne "0" ]] ; then` prevents division by 0.   Are you using the code as posted or have you modified it?

Comment: no, it is the same as the one you posted. But of course registers have increased.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk  'BEGIN { FS=OFS=", " } NR == 1 { $8="new" } NR > 1 { $8=$NF/$(NF-1) }1' input_file
id, name, country, Continent, grade, passed, failed, new
1, Louise Smith, UK, Europe, 7, 5, 1, 0.2
2, Okio Kiomoto, Japan, Asia, 9, 5, 0, 0
3, Ralph Watson, USA, Northern America, 5.6, 5, 2, 0.4
4, Mary Mcaann, South Africa, Africa, 4.7, 5, 3, 0.6
5, Jack Thomson, Australia, Oceania, 10, 5, 0, 0
6, N'dongo Mbaye, Senegal, Africa, 7.9, 5, 1, 0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested and confirmed working on `gawk 5.1.1`, `mawk 1.3.4`, `mawk 1.9.9.6`, and `macos nawk`

```
                ______ # this pair of empty double quotes
              /        # is *** essential ***, since it forces string
             /         # compare, allowing rows getting "0" value in new  
            /          # column to print out properly
            \ 
{m,n,g}awk '"" ($(_=NF += !+FS) = !/[0-9]/ ? "new"  : \
                         ($--_) / (+$--_ ? $_ : --_^--_^_))' FS = '[,][ \t]*' 
                                                            OFS = ', '
```

——————————————————————————————————

```
id, name, country, Continent, grade, passed, failed, new
1, Louise Smith, UK, Europe, 7, 5, 1, 0.2
2, Okio Kiomoto, Japan, Asia, 9, 5, 0, 0
3, Ralph Watson, USA, Northern America, 5.6, 5, 2, 0.4
4, Mary Mcaann, South Africa, Africa, 4.7, 5, 3, 0.6
5, Jack Thomson, Australia, Oceania, 10, 5, 0, 0
6, N'dongo Mbaye, Senegal, Africa, 7.9, 5, 1, 0.2
```

——————————————————————————————————

```
(condensed version :::) 

mawk '""($(_=NF+=!+FS)=!/[0-9]/?"new":($--_)/(+$--_?$_:--_^--_^_) )' FS='[,][ \t]*' OFS=', '
```